# HTTP Request Cookies - Google Location History

Tags: google-maps, session, cookies, python-requests, kml

I am using the method described here (https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2015/09/get-your-google-location-history-the-hard-way-again/) to retrieve Google Location History. This github project (https://github.com/alexattia/Maps-Location-History) uses this approach to retrieve Google Location History into a KML file.

Following the steps described and outlined here:

```
* Visit any Google Maps Timeline URL, e.g., http://www.google.com/maps/timeline?authuser=0&pb=!1m8!1m3!1i2018!2i0!3i1!2m3!1i2018!2i0!3i1
* Open the Developer's Console (Chrome: Shift-Ctrl-J, Opera: Shift-Ctrl-I)
* Refresh (F5)
* On the 'Network' tab, find the entry with 'authuser' (use the Filter)
* Right-click on the entry. Copy as cURL (bash or cmd, doesn't matter)
* The cookie is in one of the header (-H) option qualifiers with the 'cookie:' label
* The cookie_content is everything between the quotes including the "cookie:" text
```

I retrieved the required cookie and have gotten the github code to function properly (create the file and parse the data). The catch is that I have to be running the code interactively in a Jupyter Notebook and that notebook is in a browser that is logged in to my Google account.

What I need to do is to run this from a remote device (my Raspberry Pi) running a Python script in the background (i.e., not in an interactive session or terminal). In other words, I need to log in to the Google account as part of the script and then retain that session login and invoke the Google Maps Timeline URL to retrieve the location history data.

Below is the code I am using to attempt that. I have pared it down to the basic calls here for simplicity. It doesn't work (or else I wouldn't posting this ). The login succeeds but the Timeline request returns a 400 - bad request. However, the very same Timeline URL code invoked interactively works fine (because either because the login is already active or the cookie is the right cookie for that login).

```
import requests

def account_login(session, cookie_content):
    username = 'GOOGLE_ID'
    password = 'PASSWORD'
    s.auth = ('%s@gmail.com' % username, password)
    cookies = dict(cookie=cookie_content)
    #return session.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin')
    return session.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin', cookies=cookies)


cookie_content = 'cookie: cookie'

with requests.Session() as s
    r = account_login(s, cookie_content)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        cookies = dict(cookie=cookie_content)
        folder = '/home/pi/Documents/GoogleMaps/LocationHistory/LocationHistoryData/'

        url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/timeline/kml?authuser=0&pb=!1m8!1m3!1i2018!2i2!3i31!2m3!1i2018!2i2!3i31'
        r = s.get(url, cookies=cookies)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(folder + 'history-2018-03-31.kml', 'w') as f:
                f.write(r.text)
        else:
            print(r.status_code)
    else:
        print(r.status_code)
```

As I mentioned above, in the online example I am basing this on, the cookie is "pre-fetched" manually and then that string is hard-coded and used in the code. Would it be possible to grab the cookie in a programmatic way and then use that cookie string instead? In fact, this would be preferable because my concern is that the manually fetched cookie will probably go stale at some point and then I'm back to a 400 because the a bad (old) cookie will not jive with the Google account login for Timeline request.

Any guidance on how to accomplish this is much appreciated!

Regards!

Mike

Comment: So basically your question is "How to login to google with requests?". I don't know if that's possible. You may have to use `selenium`

Comment: No. I know how to log in. In fact, the code I included has a function called out specifically for that. That request returns a 200 status_code - success! 

The question is how to retain that login session and have/retrieve the needed cookie for accessing the location history (Timeline).

Comment: You can get the session cookies with `s.cookies` if that's what you mean.  But keep in mind that a 200 response doesn't necessarily mean that the login was successful. For example your `account_login` function will return 200 with any credentials.

Comment: What ought to be the proper check for a successful login?

I can say that I don't understand where the "Timeline" cookies come from specifically, but I believe they are not the cookies for the session. Otherwise the involved process of capturing them would probably not be necessary. I am perfectly fine being told that I have no idea what I'm talking about because that would be an entirely accurate statement!

Comment: Perhaps what I need is to successfully log in (with some kind of status confirmation to the effect), grab those cookies with s.cookies, and then pass that to the Timeline request? But then my question is why those cookies aren't already available to that request since it's within the session.

Perhaps I am overcomplicating this. I'll give it a shot to pass those cookies explicitly instead.

But, if anybody has any detailed knowledge and can shed some light, I'd be grateful for some guidance.

Comment: You can check if you're logged in with: a) http code b) cookies c) html (a 'welcome' message or a logout option for example). The problem here is that google uses a lot of js in its login form. I think the best option - at least for the login part - is [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Then you could pass the cookies to `requests` or continue with `selenium` (although it's quite slow and heavy)

Comment: Thanks for the clue re: the involved nature of actually authenticating. I was able to adopt the code in this project (https://github.com/tubaman/google-login) which uses selenium to sign in, and then retrieve the KML data.

Comment: Next problem - sign out afterwards! I want to sign in user 1, retrieve KML, sign out user 1, sign in user 2, retrieve user 2 KML, sign out user 2. Just requesting 'https://mail.google.com/maps/timeline?authuser=0&logout&hl=en' doesn't do it. It appears that signing out may be as involved as signing in! Lots of OAuth info for this. Not much with "simple" authentication. Help!

Comment: Sorry Mike, this is too much for me. Maybe you could ask a new question with your current code. If you don't mind some advice, try to keep your questions as short and clear as possible. Most readers would avoid long or complicated questions.

Comment: Thanks! The new question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/49635179/9373904

Comment: I'll take a look when i have some spare time. Good luck with your project!